# Unable to parse new session response, when run Protractor test in firefox

Tags: protractor

Protractor version : 5.1.1, Firefox version: 47, webdriver version : v0.15.0 
I get following error when I try to run Protractor test in Firefox:

```
[15:13:47] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:13:47] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[15:13:53] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"e8dc5d2f-a3bd-45db-89c1-a023e31e08e6","value":{"XULappId":"{ec80
30f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","acceptSslCerts":false,"appBuildId":"20160604131506","browserName":"Firefox","browserVersion":"47.0","command_id":1
,"count":1,"device":"desktop","platform":"WINDOWS_NT","platformName":"Windows_NT","platformVersion":"6.3","proxy":{},"raisesAccessibilityExceptions":f
alse,"rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"takesElementScreenshot":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"version":"47.0"}}}
[15:13:53] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"e8dc5d2f-a3bd-45db-89c1-a023e31e08e6","value":{"
XULappId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","acceptSslCerts":false,"appBuildId":"20160604131506","browserName":"Firefox","browserVersion":"47.0
","command_id":1,"count":1,"device":"desktop","platform":"WINDOWS_NT","platformName":"Windows_NT","platformVersion":"6.3","proxy":{},"raisesAccessibil
ityExceptions":false,"rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"takesElementScreenshot":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"version":"47.0"}}}
    at WebDriverError (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:445:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.js:640:55)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\direct.ts:112:25)

    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\DG_Selenium\analytics-qa\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[15:13:53] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Config file :

```
    capabilities : {
        'browserName' : 'firefox',
     },
   directConnect : true,
```

Tried running following command:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\s
elenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar" -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.e
xe
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:227)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:155)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:75)
```

Comment: Hello, Even I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: It may be due to this - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/555

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`directConnect` is not working with Firefox 52+ and Protractor 5.1.1. ([angular/protractor#4253](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4253)) Have you tried with a standalone version of `webdriver-manager` to eliminate the `directConnect` problems?

**How to use webdriver-manager:**

- `npm install webdriver-manager -g`
- `webdriver-manager update`
- `webdriver-manager start`

It will start a server on `localhost:4444/wd/hub`. Add that to your config with `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'`.

You are also using an old version of Firefox (47) with a new webdriver version. I don't know if that could cause the problem. Do you really need 47, or can you upgrade? If so, be aware that 51 is "stable" and 52 could give some troubles.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. I updated firefox to 51 and ran standalone version of `webdriver-manager`

Comment: "There are some troubles with `directConnect`" — Can you be more specific? Link to an issue maybe?

Comment: The [protractor issue-list](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/), but this is [one of the issues](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4253)

Comment: "If so, be aware that 51 is "stable" and 52 could give some troubles." — Do you happen to have a link for that as well? :) I just dislike unverifiable references to "troubles". Something should be either broken or not!