# Running protractor tests iwithin Jenkins - looking for some inspiration

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jenkins, protractor

so - I have an application which needs 3 command prompt windows open to run - this is for angular (npm start), node (node server) and webdriver (webdriver-manager start) to run.  If I do this without jenkins then I can run protractor tests using the normal "protractor " command and all works well.

I thought I'd try putting this into Jenkins (on my windows instance)

So I created a new freestyle project and had the application code checked out from git (as normal) and then used individual "Execute Windows batch command" steps for each of the steps (npm install, npm start, node server, webdriver-amanger update, webdriver-manager start, protractor )

Has anyone got experience of Node and angular with jenkins and is this the best way to run these tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this. You should modify accoding to what commands you want to run.

on Windows:
Step 1.

> npm install

Step 2.

> start npm start

Step 3. (will sleep 2 seconds)

> ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul

Step 4.

> node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js

On Linux:

> npm install

this will start and move on without waiting for it to finish

> npm start &

will wait for selenium to start

> while ! curl http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status &>/dev/null; do :;
>   done

and at last

> npm test

package.json example:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "pretest": "npm run tsc",
    "test": "npm run protractor",
    "protractor": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
    "start": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager",
    "tsc": "node node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"
},
```

https://github.com/andriyze/proTR/blob/master/package.json

Comment: That was mostly what I had - the only difference was you had node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js  Using that I can see a firefox window launch, but I get an error or "unable to parse new sessions response:"  Still not working but a lot better than before

Comment: not sure if this is your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194582/unable-to-parse-new-session-response-when-run-protractor-test-in-firefox

Comment: you can try update browsers, protractor, selenium to latest versions. check if gecko/chrome driver files are in windows path

Comment: @andryize - Before I left on Friday I realised the browser was a really old one - so I updated this and had tests running (yey) - my report wasn't produced, but that is another issue (suspecting permissions on the directory)

Comment: great! in case you want to setup reporters here is an example how i did it https://github.com/andriyze/proTR/blob/master/protractor.conf.js